# ipywidgets button only works once: use the same button multiple times

Tags: button, jupyter-notebook, onclick, display, ipywidgets

I have the following class and I have 4 buttons to go to:

- the next image
- the previous image
- the last image
- the first image

Working with **jupyter notebook**, I want to click on the required button, which goes to the associated image. But the button **only works once** (the same or another button) and I can't go through all images.

How can I do to use buttons multiple times with this class?

```
class DisplayButtons:
    
    def __init__(self, low_path, restored_path):
        self.left = None
        self.right = None
        self.top_right = None
        self.top_left = None
        self.index = None
        self.box = None
        self.low_path = low_path
        self.restored_path = restored_path
        
    def plot_restoration(self):
        clear_output()
        display(self.box)

        img = imread(self.low_path[self.index])
        if img.ndim == 3: img = img[0]
        height, width = img.shape
        if height < 450: height, width = height * 2, width * 2
        img_restored = imread(self.restored_path[self.index])
        plt.figure(figsize = (height/50, width/50))
        plt.subplot(1, 2, 1)
        plt.imshow(img)
        plt.subplot(1, 2, 2)
        plt.imshow(img_restored)
        plt.show()
        
    def is_end(self):
        return self.index == len(self.low_path) - 1
    
    def is_start(self):
        return self.index == 0
    
    def is_displayed(self):
        return self.index is not None
        
    def go_top_left(self):
        if not self.is_start():
            self.initialize()
        
    def initialize(self):
        self.index=0
        self.plot_restoration()    
    
    def go_left(self):
        if not self.is_displayed or self.is_start():
            self.initialize()
        else: 
            self.index -= 1
            self.plot_restoration()

    def go_right(self):
        if not self.is_end():
            self.index += 1
            self.plot_restoration()

    def go_top_right(self):
        if not self.is_end():
            self.index = len(self.low_path) - 1
            self.plot_restoration()
            
    def set_buttons(self):
        # Define buttons
        scroll = ['⇤', '←', '→', '⇥']
        layout = widgets.Layout(width='auto', height='auto')
        buttons = [Button(description=s, layout = layout) for s in scroll]
        button_1, button_2, button_3, button_4 = buttons

        box_1 = VBox([buttons[0]])
        box_2 = VBox([buttons[1]])
        box_3 = VBox([buttons[2]])
        box_4 = VBox([buttons[3]])
        self.box = HBox([box_1, box_2, box_3, box_4])
        
        # Launch of function when click
        button_1.on_click(self.go_top_left())
        button_2.on_click(self.go_left())
        button_3.on_click(self.go_right())
        button_4.on_click(self.go_top_right())
        
        display(self.box)
```

Thanks for your help

Comment: Should only the function name be passed to those `.on_click()`, like `button_1.on_click(self.go_top_left)`?

Answer (score 1):

1. Pass the method reference instead of calling the method
2. Add a 2nd argument to the buttons' event handlers, representing the clicked button widget instance.
3. You are going to need to some other logic updates, but the first two points should cover enough how to use the buttons multiple times

   ```py
   from ipywidgets import Button, HBox, Layout, VBox

   class DisplayButtons:

       def __init__(self, low_path, restored_path):
           self.left = None
           self.right = None
           self.top_right = None
           self.top_left = None
           self.index = None
           self.box = None
           self.low_path = low_path
           self.restored_path = restored_path

       def plot_restoration(self):
           clear_output()
           display(self.box)

           img = imread(self.low_path[self.index])
           if img.ndim == 3: img = img[0]
           height, width = img.shape
           if height < 450: height, width = height * 2, width * 2
           img_restored = imread(self.restored_path[self.index])
           plt.figure(figsize = (height/50, width/50))
           plt.subplot(1, 2, 1)
           plt.imshow(img)
           plt.subplot(1, 2, 2)
           plt.imshow(img_restored)
           plt.show()

       def is_end(self):
           return self.index == len(self.low_path) - 1

       def is_start(self):
           return self.index == 0

       def is_displayed(self):
           return self.index is not None

       def go_top_left(self, b): # <- 2. button argument
           if not self.is_start():
               self.initialize()

       def initialize(self):
           self.index=0
           self.plot_restoration()    

       def go_left(self, b): # <- 2. button argument
           if not self.is_displayed or self.is_start():
               self.initialize()
           else: 
               self.index -= 1
               self.plot_restoration()

       def go_right(self, b): # <- 2. button argument
           if not self.is_end():
               self.index += 1
               self.plot_restoration()

       def go_top_right(self, b): # <- 2. button argument
           if not self.is_end():
               self.index = len(self.low_path) - 1
               self.plot_restoration()

       def set_buttons(self):
           # Define buttons
           scroll = ['⇤', '←', '→', '⇥']
           layout = widgets.Layout(width='auto', height='auto')
           buttons = [Button(description=s, layout = layout) for s in scroll]
           button_1, button_2, button_3, button_4 = buttons

           box_1 = VBox([buttons[0]])
           box_2 = VBox([buttons[1]])
           box_3 = VBox([buttons[2]])
           box_4 = VBox([buttons[3]])
           self.box = HBox([box_1, box_2, box_3, box_4])

           # Launch of function when click
           button_1.on_click(self.go_top_left) # <- 1. method reference
           button_2.on_click(self.go_left) # <- 1. method reference
           button_3.on_click(self.go_right) # <- 1. method reference
           button_4.on_click(self.go_top_right) # <- 1. method reference

           display(self.box)
   ```

Comment: Thank you very much ! It is working. Why is it needed to add"event=None" ?

Comment: Note that `Button` is from `ipywidgets` module, so It is not an event object.  It is the button instance instead.